# MongoDB - Multiple query and single document result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, query-optimization

I'm creating an insights dashboard and I have some many data and stored count of this but I need consolidate this in one document. (umm is hard to explain in words), e.g.

Site collection:

```
{
 Name: "..."
 ApiKey: "SomeUnique1"
 Insights:
 {
   sumOfData: 5,
   anotherSum: 14
 }
},
{
     Name: "..."
     ApiKey: "SomeUnique2"
     Insights:
     {
       sumOfData: 5,
       anotherSum: 1
     }
    },...
```

I want to retrieve next following data:

```
{
     ChartDashboard: "Usage"
     Insights:
     {
       sumOfData: 10,
       anotherSum: 15
     }
    }
```

I read that $and operator can retrieve with some ApiKey's properties, but MongoDB have any operator to make this?

Comment: use aggregation for this. Take a look at the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator

Comment: umm yeah!, this is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework. An example is the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ '$group':
   {
    _id:null, 
   'ChartDashboard':'Usage',
   'sumOfData':{$sum:'$Insights.sumOfData'},
   'anotherSum':{$sum:'$Insights.sumOfData'}
   }
}
])
```

and the result of that will be:

```
{
    '_id' : null,
    'ChartDashboard' : 'Usage',
    'sumOfData' : 10,
    'anotherSum' : 15 
}
```